# Only the first entry of .bib file can be cited

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing

I use the custom document class

`\documentclass{MastersDoctoralThesis}`

but hope, my question is more general. In my head there is

`\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{example.bib}`

My `example.bib`:

```
@article{Reference1,
Abstract = {We have developed an enhanced Littrow configuration extended cavity diode laser (ECDL) that can be tuned without changing the direction of the output beam. The output of a conventional Littrow ECDL is reflected from a plane mirror fixed parallel to the tuning diffraction grating. Using a free-space Michelson wavemeter to measure the laser wavelength, we can tune the laser over a range greater than 10 nm without any alteration of alignment.},
Author = {C. J. Hawthorn and K. P. Weber and R. E. Scholten},
Journal = {Review of Scientific Instruments},
Month = {12},
Number = {12},
Numpages = {3},
Pages = {4477--4479},
Title = {Littrow Configuration Tunable External Cavity Diode Laser with Fixed Direction Output Beam},
Volume = {72},
Url = {http://link.aip.org/link/?RSI/72/4477/1},
Year = {2001}}

@article{Reference2,
Abstract = {We present a review of the use of diode lasers in atomic physics with an extensive list of references. We discuss the relevant characteristics of diode lasers and explain how to purchase and use them. We also review the various techniques that have been used to control and narrow the spectral outputs of diode lasers. Finally we present a number of examples illustrating the use of diode lasers in atomic physics experiments. Review of Scientific Instruments is copyrighted by The American Institute of Physics.},
Author = {Carl E. Wieman and Leo Hollberg},
Journal = {Review of Scientific Instruments},
Keywords = {Diode Laser},
Month = {1},
Number = {1},
Numpages = {20},
Pages = {1--20},
Title = {Using Diode Lasers for Atomic Physics},
Volume = {62},
Url = {http://link.aip.org/link/?RSI/62/1/1},
Year = {1991}}
```

When I use `\cite{}` in my main, I can only sucessfully use `\cite{Reference1}`, not `\cite{Reference2}`. Second only prints "Reference2" in bold. It's not about the Reference2-entry specifically, as it's the other way around, when I put Reference2 before Reference1 in the `.bib`.

Tell me if you need more information. I firstly wanted to make sure this isn't a common or obvious problem.

Comment: Does the file 'example.blg' (the log created by bibtex) contain any warning messages? If so, what are they?

Comment: Did you follow the pdfLaTeX > BibTeX > pdfLaTeX > pdfLaTeX compile sequence?

Comment: I do not have the custom class file, otherwise, the example works as expected for me.

Comment: Thank you all!
Werners assumption was correct, I didn't compile specifically for BibTex. I will formulate an answer.

Comment: @Josephus: I think this is probably a sufficient duplicate reference: [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/5764)